# RMMapView cache

Tags: ios, mapbox

There is lack of information about implementing MapBox cache on iOS. Can anybody please provide good example of using [RMTileCache beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource..] and then loading these cached data to map?

I'm using:

```
RMSphericalTrapezium rect = [mapView latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox];
mapView.tileCache.backgroundCacheDelegate = self;
[mapView.tileCache beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource:mapView.tileSource
                                               southWest:rect.southWest
                                               northEast:rect.northEast
                                                 minZoom:8.0
                                                 maxZoom:19.0];
mapView.tileCache = tileCache;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is the canonical sample project: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk-offline

Source: I wrote it.